# How to override background of button component without needing to override hover state

Tags: material-ui

When using Material-UI/Styles, I find that changing the background property of a button to a solid color causes the hover state to make the button super white. What is the "correct" way to override the background of a button (component), and why does it work with the linear gradient buttons in the examples (see below)?

I have tried inline css, and found that the issue does not persist. I have seen that a button with a background of linear gradient does not have this issue either.

Simply put, go into the CodeSandbox and change the background property to a solid color, and then hover over the button. You will see what I am talking about.

You can try this out using the CodeSandbox Link https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-qqnde?fontsize=14

I expect to be able to change the background color of a button component to a different color without having to use a theme yet.

Comment: You need to specify the hover color (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-dyuky) as well otherwise you get the same hover color as when using `Button` without the styling you have added.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I understand that, but I still cant figure out why the examples that use a linear gradient background dont require a declared property for the hover state color. Do you know why?

Comment: [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) sets the `background-image` property. The [default Material-UI hover styling](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L23) only changes the `background-color` property. The `background-image` wins over the `background-color`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank God! That finally makes sense. I know its not a big deal, but that one question has been nagging me all day. Cheers Mate!